# How to convert a manual sales calculator script into an automatic sales calculator script?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I have this manual javascript

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function applyTax(){
      var inputAmount = document.getElementById( 'dollars' ).value;
      var salesTaxGst = (inputAmount / 100) * 5;
      var salesTaxPst =  (inputAmount / 100) * 9.975;
      var totalAmount = (inputAmount*1) + (salesTaxGst * 1) +(salesTaxPst * 1) ;

      document.getElementById( 'requestedAmount' ).innerHTML = inputAmount;
      document.getElementById( 'requestedTaxGst' ).innerHTML = salesTaxGst;
      document.getElementById( 'requestedTaxPst' ).innerHTML = salesTaxPst;
      document.getElementById( 'requestedTotal' ).innerHTML = totalAmount;
    }

    </script>
</head>
```

And the html

```
<body>

<input type="text" id="dollars" />
<input type="button" onclick="applyTax();" value="Calculate" />

<div id="requestedAmount"> </div>
<div id="requestedTaxGst"> </div>
<div id="requestedTaxPst"> </div>
<div id="requestedTotal"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

So basically this script needs user to input data manually to calculate taxes. I'm trying to convert it into an automatic sales tax calculator for say an eCommerce site.

**Cart page:**

```
    <div id="store_container">
            <div id="store">


                <%-- Left Navigation --%>
                <div style="text-align: center;" id="category">
                    <div id="items"><fmt:message key='summary'/>
                    </div>


                    <div class="cat_row">

                        <div style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-weight: bold;"><span
                                    style="background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);"><fmt:message key='CartCategoryLabel1'/></span></span><br>


                            <%-- Start of Left Nav Widgets--%>
                            <ul style="list-style-type: none;">

                                <%-- clear cart widget --%>
                                <c:set var="value">
                                <c:choose>
                                <%-- if 'selectedCategory' session object exists, send user to previously viewed category --%>
                                        <c:when test="${!empty selectedCategory}">

                                        </c:when>

                                        <%-- otherwise send user to welcome page --%>
                                <c:otherwise>

                                    </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
                         </c:set>                     
                <c:url var="url" value="${value}"/>
                <li><a href="viewCart?clear=true"><fmt:message key='ClearCart'/></a></li>

                    <%-- checkout widget --%>
                    <c:if test="${!empty cart && cart.numberOfItems != 0}">
                <li><a href="checkout"><fmt:message key='Checkout'/></a></li>
                </c:if>


                                <%-- continue shopping widget --%>
        <c:set var="value">
            <c:choose>
                <%-- if 'selectedCategory' session object exists, send user to previously viewed category --%>
                <c:when test="${!empty selectedCategory}">
                    category
                </c:when>
                <%-- otherwise send user to welcome page --%>
                <c:otherwise>
                    index.jsp
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </c:set>
                                <li style="background-color: rgb(198, 255, 201);"><a href="${value}"><fmt:message key='ContinueShopping'/></a></li>
                            </ul>

                            <br>
                            <span style="text-decoration: underline;"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <%-- End of Left Navigation --%>


                <%-- Start of Cart Breadcrumbs --%>
                <div style="text-align: center;" id="thumbnails">
                    <div id="items">My shopping cart<br>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <div style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">
                        <div style="text-align: center;"><big></big></div>

                        <%-- Subtotal of cart--%>
                        <c:if test="${!empty cart && cart.numberOfItems != 0}">
                            <div style="text-align: center;" class="item_col"><big><fmt:message key='Subtotal'/> (${cart.subtotal})<br>
                                </big></div>
                            <big></big>
                        </c:if>
                        <%-- End Subtotal of cart--%>




                        <%-- Number of items in cart--%>
                        <div style="text-align: center;" class="item_col2">

                            <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${cart.numberOfItems > 1}">
            <big><fmt:message key='YouHave'/> (${cart.numberOfItems}) <fmt:message key='ItemsInYourCart'/><br></big>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${cart.numberOfItems == 1}">
            <big><fmt:message key='YouHave'/> (${cart.numberOfItems}) <fmt:message key='ItemsInYourCart'/><br></big>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <big><fmt:message key='EmptyShoppingCart'/><br></big>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
                        </div>

                        <div style="text-align: center;"><big></big></div>
                    </div>
                    <big><br style="font-weight: bold;">
                    </big>
                    <%-- End of cart Breadcrumbs --%>       



                    <%-- Start of Products Table--%>        
                    <div style="font-weight: bold;" id="thumb_container"> 
                        <div style="text-align: left;">
                            <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0"
                                   cellspacing="0">

                                <c:forEach var="cartItem" items="${cart.items}" varStatus="iter">
                                    <c:set var="product" value="${cartItem.product}"/>

                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="${((iter.index % 2) == 0) ? 'lightBlue' : 'white'}">
                                            <td
                                                style="vertical-align: middle; width: 196px; text-align: center; height: 140px;"><img class="img" src="${initParam.productImagePath}${product.name}.jpg"<br>
                                            </td>
                                            <td
                                                style="vertical-align: middle; width: 164px; text-align: center; height: 140px;">${product.name}<br>
                                            </td>
                                            <td

                                                style="vertical-align: middle; width: 100px; text-align: center; height: 140px;">${product.price}<br>
                                            </td>
                                            <td
                                                style="vertical-align: middle; width: 180px; text-align: center; height: 140px;"><form action="addToWishlist" method="post"><br><br> <input
name="productId" value="${product.id}" type="hidden"> <input class="submit"
value="Add To Wishlist" type="submit"></form><br>
                                            </td>
                                            <td
                                                style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; height: 140px; width: 180px; padding-top:35px;"><form action="updateCart" method="post">
                                                    <input type="hidden"
                                                           name="productId"
                                                           value="${product.id}">

                                                    <input type="text"
                                                           maxlength="2"
                                                           size="2"
                                                           value="${cartItem.quantity}"
                                                           name="quantity"
                                                           style="margin:0px">

                                                    <input class="updateButton"  type="submit"
                                                           name="submit"
                                                           value="update">

                                                </form><br>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>

                                </c:forEach>
                            </table>


                            <%-- End of Products Table--%>
```

So I'm thinking in order to convert the script to calculate cart subtotal **automatically** I would only have to change few things around by declaring different variables?

Example:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function applyTax(){
  var ${cart.subtotal} = document.getElementById( 'cartSubtotal' ).value;
  var salesTaxGst = (${cart.subtotal} / 100) * 5;
  var salesTaxPst =  (${cart.subtotal} / 100) * 9.975;
  var totalAmount = (${cart.subtotal}*1) + (salesTaxGst * 1) +(salesTaxPst * 1) ;

  document.getElementById( 'cartSubtotal' ).innerHTML = ${cart.subtotal} ;
  document.getElementById( 'taxGst' ).innerHTML = salesTaxGst;
  document.getElementById( 'taxPst' ).innerHTML = salesTaxPst;
  document.getElementById( 'cartTotal' ).innerHTML = totalAmount;
}
</script>
</head>


<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="cartSubtotal" />
<input type="button" onload="applyTax();" value="Calculate" />

<div id="cartSubtotal"> </div>
<div id="taxGst"> </div>
<div id="taxPst"> </div>
<div id="cartTotal"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

------ EDIT ----

For a better vision, this is a screenshot from Forever 21 checkout process. You see, at the end of the page, they display the `total amount = cart subtotal + tax + shipping`. This is exactly what i'm trying to do with a script.

Snapshot:
[image: FE21 Order Summary]

Comment: what's with all the `${cart.subtotal}` syntax? Is that something you made up or is it from a templating language?

Comment: @charlietfl: the `${cart.subtotal}` is a variable used to display the subtotal of the customer cart. I will put the code so it's clearer..

Comment: why would that be used for a javascript variable name? variable name can't be numeric. Show the browser source version of the script

Comment: @charlietfl: My bad. But how would I extract the subtotal of a given cart if I don't declare the variable used in the cart page to display subtotal?

Comment: You seem to be getting server code and javascript code mixed up. They run in different environments and at different times. A normal javascript variable would be something like `var subTotal = `

Comment: Explain what you mean by `automatic`? Normally a calculator would have `<input>` elements and change event handlers to intialize the calculations

Comment: @charlietfl: Yes. But then how would I extract the amount of cart subtotal stated in the cart page? I'm trying to do a conversion from manual script into automatic. I need to remove the input fields so that the app calculates everything by itself without needing user input... If you run first script, user needs to enter a number to get calculation. I try to convert the input text field so it  is replaced by the cart subtotal instead.

Comment: Then why do you need javascript for that? If all you want is read only, generate the html at back end

Comment: @charlietfl: Well it's the easiest way? Any more intelligent idea is welcome dude...

Comment: I am just very confused at what the objectives are along with the code that originally made little sense. Suggest you write up a clear definition of the flow process of this cart. Right now I just don't get it

Comment: @charlietfl: The formula in itself isn't bad since it's doing the job right which is calculating 2 taxes from a given amount. The first script works perfectly fine. I was just trying to mess around and try to convert it into a read-only script... But in order for the script to work, I need to declare the cart subtotal found in the cart page... I don't think html alone could do the job reason why I used some javascript...

Comment: but it's 100% read only right? In which case you can simply do it with server code. Sure you can do it with javascript but that's not really the right tool for the job. If you want to use javascript you simply need to write one value to a javascript variable something like `var subtotal = <% cart.subtotal %>`. My java is very weak, not sure what output syntax is precisely

Comment: @charlietfl: I hear you dude. How would you have done it in case of read-only script, without javascript? How would you write the whole code?

Comment: So do you want to let the user add things to cart and then calculate those stuff automatically ? because the last code is identical to the first(only a name changed)

Comment: @niceman: Hey man thanks for replying. Actually I already have the code in cart page that automatically calculate subtotal when user adds items. All I need is some code for the checkout page so the sales taxes are added to the subtotal to show user his total.

Comment: @niceman: this is the code for calculating the totalAmount with the taxes `var totalAmount = (${cart.subtotal}*1) + (salesTaxGst * 1) +(salesTaxPst * 1) ;`. Last dude said to use only server code since its a read-only script. But I am using javascript. Any idea?

Comment: @user23524697 I can answer but for better answer, add the php code(don't remove the code included in post now, just add)

Comment: @niceman: the php code? You mean the whole code for the cart page?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean

Comment: @niceman: Alright. I just added the whole code. Hope it helps. Thanks mate.

Comment: @user23524697 well I thought you're programming php but what you're programming is plain javascript, anyway sorry but I don't know the <c:> tags , so sorry, can't really answer

Comment: but you should somehow call the variable from the cartpage not to name a new variable and a new html component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution to my best interpretation to what you want. To me it seems like you want to take the displayed subtotal and calculate the taxes via javascript. This probably isn't the best way to go about it as I assume you'll be using those values later during the checkout process and it'd behove you to calculate those values on the backend then display them rather than through javascript, but I digress.

**Javascript:**

```
function applyTax(){
  var cartSubTotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById( 'cartSubtotal' ).innerHTML);
  console.log(cartSubTotal);
  var salesTaxGst = (cartSubTotal / 100) * 5;
  var salesTaxPst =  (cartSubTotal / 100) * 9.975;
  var totalAmount = (cartSubTotal*1) + (salesTaxGst * 1) +(salesTaxPst * 1) ;

  document.getElementById( 'cartSubtotal' ).innerHTML = cartSubTotal.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById( 'taxGst' ).innerHTML = salesTaxGst.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById( 'taxPst' ).innerHTML = salesTaxPst.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById( 'cartTotal' ).innerHTML = totalAmount.toFixed(2);
}

// Call the applyTax() when the window finishes loading...
window.onload = function() {
  applyTax();
}
```

**Note:** I added toFixed(2) to include the "cents" placeholders, even when their value is zero.

Using the following **HTML**:

```
<div class="main">
  <h1>Cart</h1>
  <p>Cart Subtotal: $<span id="cartSubtotal">100.00</span></p>
  <p>Sales Tax GST: $<span id="taxGst"></span></p>
  <p>Sales Tax PST: $<span id="taxPst"></span></p>
  <p>Final Total: $<span id="cartTotal"></span></p>
</div>
```

Would **display** something that looked like this:

```
Cart

Cart Subtotal: $100.00
Sales Tax GST: $5.00
Sales Tax PST: $9.97
Final Total: $114.97
```

Save that you're already inserting the price as a floating-point number into the item with the id `cartSubtotal`

Maybe a CodePen example to play with? http://codepen.io/scrapcode/pen/GgYXaQ

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, you're hitting the nail. This is what I'm trying to do. I will try your code asap and get back to you. As for handling the values in back-end, I thought about it, as well. Are you talking about setting the two values as `<context-parameters/>` in web.xml? Then calling the values in the `ControllerServlet`?

Comment: Your backend solution would vary _greatly_ depending on your tech stack. Just make sure you're not using the values calculated by javascript directly from the DOM to process real transactions.

Comment: I will not handle the real transactions myself. In real time, the form will be redirected  to a third party... You said using JavaScript wasn't the best way to go about the subject. In your humble opinion, how would you go about doing what I'm trying to do? I'm interesting to know because so far you've understood the subject pretty well.

Comment: @user23524697: If you're just forwarding the static form somewhere else, then that's perfectly fine. As long as those calculations are not use dynamically, e.g., the user will then checkout through a payment processor that uses the innerHTML of `.cartTotal` as the total price.

Comment: And say if it is used dynamically, then what would you suggest?

Comment: I'd suggest performing these calculations on the backend (server side) before sending to your payment processor via API or whatnot. If you're unsure about how you'd go about securely processing transactions, you might want to bring in professional assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you were trying to do:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="cartSubtotal" />
  <input type="button" onClick="applyTax();" value="Calculate" />
  <div id="cartSubtotal"></div>
  <div id="taxGst"></div>
  <div id="taxPst"></div>
  <div id="cartTotal"></div>
  <script>
    function applyTax() {
      var cartSubtotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cartSubtotal').value);
      if (!isNaN(cartSubtotal)){
        var salesTaxGst = (cartSubtotal / 100) * 5;
        var salesTaxPst = (cartSubtotal / 100) * 9.975;
        var totalAmount = cartSubtotal + salesTaxGst + salesTaxPst;
        document.getElementById('cartSubtotal').innerHTML = "Subtotal: " + cartSubtotal;
        document.getElementById('taxGst').innerHTML = "Sales tax GST: " + salesTaxGst;
        document.getElementById('taxPst').innerHTML = "Sales tax PST: " + salesTaxPst;
        document.getElementById('cartTotal').innerHTML = "Total amount: " + totalAmount;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

However even after keeping on reading your subject things are not clear for you I think.
You have a server that generates pages, everything that is generated will process at the server side, therefore you can use your notations such as  or ${..}. But once this page is sent to the client (where the client is using javascript) you cannot change those informations anymore because you are not on a server anymore.

If you want to update data on your server you will have to contact the server again via an HTTP request or an Ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try your code in a min and get back to you.

Comment: Your script works but I think it's the whole thing that is confusing. Maybe I shouldn't try to convert the script into automatic and just try to create another one that best serves the purpose of the subject. See I do not need any `input` field. What i'm trying to do is just a sales calculation on the checkout page like in any other online store when you pay and they display the `total amount = tax + tax + shipping`. This is all what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Reason why, in my personal opinion, javascripts is needed to call the statements. Otherwise how would the system know how to make the calculations? Take the cart page for instance. If we look at the code used, let's take `product_name` for instance, I call the statements using `${ }` so the application knows where to look to get the required information. In my opinion I think I need to do the same to display the calculation on the checkout page. I will post the code used for the checkout page so you understand better what i`m trying to do...

Comment: See EDIT for a better understanding. I uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: Hi sorry I didn't notice your messages I was quite busy those days. You are using a server in Java and JSP to generate your page is it correct ? Then it is better if you do all the calculation in the Java side and just render it on the div elements rather than using JavaScript which has no meaning to do this. Also can you confirm that the cart subtotal doesn't need to be change on the page once it's calculated ?